# grouping together values in python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of course objects with student score data:

```
c1.name = "c1"  # c1 is a course with 2 attributes
c1.records = { "student1": 100, "student2": 90 }
c2.name = "c2"
c2.records = { "student1": 100, "student2": 40, "student3": 80 }
# and other courses
```

and I want to group them together like so:

```
{ "student1": { 100: ["c1", "c2"] },  # student1 scored 100 in both courses
  "student2": { 90: ["c1"], 40: ["c2"] },
  "student3": { 80: ["c2"] } }
```

How can I write this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the `setdefault` proposed by Paul Becotte in his answer, there is also `collections.defaultdict` which similarly allows for a considerable simplification of the algorithm by providing default values internally.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

course_data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for course in courses:
    for student, score in course.records.items():
        course_data[student][score].append(course.name)
```

Comment: yeah, that's how I write things like this normally- but figured trying to explain 'lambda' for a homework assignment was a bad idea ;)

Comment: Thank you @fsimonjetz! FYI @PaulBecotte this was not a homework assignment.

Comment: homework assignment or beginner experiment, the point still stands that it is harder to explain what defaultdict with a lambda is doing :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you need to accomplish- you want to iterate through your objects and build a data structure.

```
students = {}
for course in courses:
```

Now, each course has a dict of students-

```
for student_name, grade in course.records.items():
```

Finally, we need to build the data structure you want-

```
if student_name not in students:
  students[student_name] = {}
if grade not in students[student_name]:
  students[student_name][grade] = []
students[student_name][grade].append(course.name)
```

Nice and straightforward- build up your nested structure as you go.

Tip 1-

```
students.setdefault(student_name, {}).setdefault(grade, []).append(course.name)
```

Setdefault will let you do the "if not in, create new key" part in one step.

Tip 2-

Seems like it'd make more sense for your inner dict to have the course name as the key instead of the grade?